# linux redhat mysql 5.7.39 cannot start

Tags: mysql, linux

I've installed mysql(The version is:mysql-5.7.39-1.el7.x86_64.rpm-bundle.tar) in Linux redhat, while after the installation, I can't start mysqld.service successfully.The Terminal indicates that:

[jsadmin@ahq-vsvr10-0120 new]$ sudo systemctl start mysqld.service
Job for mysqld.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status mysqld.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.

```
The result for "journalctl -xe" is:
[jsadmin@ahq-vsvr10-0120 /]$ journalctl -xe
Nov 16 22:31:36 ahq-vsvr10-0120 mysqld[11028]: 2022-11-16T14:31:36.840843Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FIELDS'
Nov 16 22:31:36 ahq-vsvr10-0120 mysqld[11028]: 2022-11-16T14:31:36.840848Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_COLUMNS'
Nov 16 22:31:36 ahq-vsvr10-0120 mysqld[11028]: 2022-11-16T14:31:36.840853Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_INDEXES'
Nov 16 22:31:36 ahq-vsvr10-0120 mysqld[11028]: 2022-11-16T14:31:36.840858Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLESTATS'
Nov 16 22:31:36 ahq-vsvr10-0120 mysqld[11028]: 2022-11-16T14:31:36.840863Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLES'
Nov 16 22:31:36 ahq-vsvr10-0120 mysqld[11028]: 2022-11-16T14:31:36.840868Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_INDEX_TABLE'
Nov 16 22:31:36 ahq-vsvr10-0120 mysqld[11028]: 2022-11-16T14:31:36.840873Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_INDEX_CACHE'
Nov 16 22:31:36 ahq-vsvr10-0120 mysqld[11028]: 2022-11-16T14:31:36.840878Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_CONFIG'
Nov 16 22:31:36 ahq-vsvr10-0120 mysqld[11028]: 2022-11-16T14:31:36.840883Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_BEING_DELETED'
Nov 16 22:31:36 ahq-vsvr10-0120 mysqld[11028]: 2022-11-16T14:31:36.840888Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_DELETED'
Nov 16 22:31:36 ahq-vsvr10-0120 mysqld[11028]: 2022-11-16T14:31:36.840893Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_DEFAULT_STOPWORD'
Nov 16 22:31:36 ahq-vsvr10-0120 mysqld[11028]: 2022-11-16T14:31:36.840898Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_METRICS'
Nov 16 22:31:36 ahq-vsvr10-0120 mysqld[11028]: 2022-11-16T14:31:36.840903Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_TEMP_TABLE_INFO'
Nov 16 22:31:36 ahq-vsvr10-0120 mysqld[11028]: 2022-11-16T14:31:36.840908Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_POOL_STATS'
Nov 16 22:31:36 ahq-vsvr10-0120 mysqld[11028]: 2022-11-16T14:31:36.840913Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE_LRU'
Nov 16 22:31:36 ahq-vsvr10-0120 mysqld[11028]: 2022-11-16T14:31:36.840918Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE'
Nov 16 22:31:36 ahq-vsvr10-0120 mysqld[11028]: 2022-11-16T14:31:36.840922Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_PER_INDEX_RESET'
Nov 16 22:31:36 ahq-vsvr10-0120 mysqld[11028]: 2022-11-16T14:31:36.840927Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_PER_INDEX'
Nov 16 22:31:36 ahq-vsvr10-0120 mysqld[11028]: 2022-11-16T14:31:36.840932Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMPMEM_RESET'
Nov 16 22:31:36 ahq-vsvr10-0120 mysqld[11028]: 2022-11-16T14:31:36.840937Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMPMEM'
Nov 16 22:31:36 ahq-vsvr10-0120 mysqld[11028]: 2022-11-16T14:31:36.840942Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_RESET'
Nov 16 22:31:36 ahq-vsvr10-0120 mysqld[11028]: 2022-11-16T14:31:36.840947Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP'
Nov 16 22:31:36 ahq-vsvr10-0120 mysqld[11028]: 2022-11-16T14:31:36.840952Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_LOCK_WAITS'
Nov 16 22:31:36 ahq-vsvr10-0120 mysqld[11028]: 2022-11-16T14:31:36.840956Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_LOCKS'
Nov 16 22:31:36 ahq-vsvr10-0120 mysqld[11028]: 2022-11-16T14:31:36.840961Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_TRX'
Nov 16 22:31:36 ahq-vsvr10-0120 mysqld[11028]: 2022-11-16T14:31:36.840966Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'InnoDB'
Nov 16 22:31:36 ahq-vsvr10-0120 mysqld[11028]: 2022-11-16T14:31:36.841107Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: FTS optimize thread exiting.
Nov 16 22:31:36 ahq-vsvr10-0120 mysqld[11028]: 2022-11-16T14:31:36.841684Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
Nov 16 22:31:36 ahq-vsvr10-0120 mysqld[11028]: 2022-11-16T14:31:36.942060Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Dumping buffer pool(s) to /data/mysql/ib_buffer_pool
Nov 16 22:31:36 ahq-vsvr10-0120 mysqld[11028]: 2022-11-16T14:31:36.943909Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) dump completed at 221116 22:31:36
Nov 16 22:31:37 ahq-vsvr10-0120 sshd[11060]: Accepted password for jsadmin from 10.1.19.72 port 58014 ssh2
```

The result for "systemctl status mysqld.service" is:

```
[jsadmin@ahq-vsvr10-0120 /]$ systemctl status mysqld.service -l
● mysqld.service - MySQL Server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/mysqld.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: deactivating (stop-sigterm) (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2022-11-16 22:03:46 CST; 30min ago
     Docs: man:mysqld(8)
           http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/en/using-systemd.html
  Process: 13625 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld --daemonize --pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid $MYSQLD_OPTS (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 13607 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/mysqld_pre_systemd (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 110983 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   CGroup: /system.slice/mysqld.service
           └─13628 /usr/sbin/mysqld --daemonize --pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid

Nov 16 22:34:00 ahq-vsvr10-0120 mysqld[13625]: 2022-11-16T14:34:00.082340Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
Nov 16 22:34:00 ahq-vsvr10-0120 mysqld[13625]: 2022-11-16T14:34:00.082939Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file './ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
Nov 16 22:34:00 ahq-vsvr10-0120 mysqld[13625]: 2022-11-16T14:34:00.091421Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: File './ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
Nov 16 22:34:00 ahq-vsvr10-0120 mysqld[13625]: 2022-11-16T14:34:00.136359Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 96 redo rollback segment(s) found. 96 redo rollback segment(s) are active.
Nov 16 22:34:00 ahq-vsvr10-0120 mysqld[13625]: 2022-11-16T14:34:00.136434Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 32 non-redo rollback segment(s) are active.
Nov 16 22:34:00 ahq-vsvr10-0120 mysqld[13625]: 2022-11-16T14:34:00.138057Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
Nov 16 22:34:00 ahq-vsvr10-0120 mysqld[13625]: 2022-11-16T14:34:00.188733Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 5.7.39 started; log sequence number 3718895665
Nov 16 22:34:00 ahq-vsvr10-0120 mysqld[13625]: 2022-11-16T14:34:00.189136Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from /data/mysql/ib_buffer_pool
Nov 16 22:34:00 ahq-vsvr10-0120 mysqld[13625]: 2022-11-16T14:34:00.189588Z 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
Nov 16 22:34:00 ahq-vsvr10-0120 systemd[1]: mysqld.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
```

/ect/my.inf file is:

```
[jsadmin@ahq-vsvr10-0119 etc]$ cat my.cnf
[mysql]
 port                           = 3306
 [mysqld]
sql_mode='STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION' 
 user                           = mysql
 default-storage-engine         = InnoDB
 lower_case_table_names         = 1
max_allowed_packet = 1000M 
 key-buffer-size                = 32M
 read-buffer-size               = 1M
 read-rnd-buffer-size           = 4M
 bulk-insert-buffer-size        = 8M
 myisam-sort-buffer-size        = 8M
 myisam-max-sort-file-size      = 1G
 myisam-repair-threads          = 1
 group_concat_max_len           = 4294967295
 max-allowed-packet             = 32M
 max-connect-errors             = 1000000
 datadir                        = /data/mysql/
server-id = 1

log-bin=/data/mysql/mysql-bin.log
binlog_format=mixed
#binlog-do-db=virt
#binlog-ignore-db=mysql  
#binlog-ignore-db=information_schema  
#binlog-ignore-db=performance_schema  
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=1
sync_binlog=1  
expire_logs_days = 5
auto_increment_increment=2
auto_increment_offset=1


 tmp-table-size                 = 64M
 max-heap-table-size            = 64M
 query-cache-type               = 0
 query-cache-size               = 0
 max-connections                = 4000
 thread-cache-size              = 1000
 open-files-limit               = 65535
 table-definition-cache         = 512
 table-open-cache               = 1024
 innodb-flush-method            = O_DIRECT
 innodb-log-files-in-group      = 2
 innodb-log-file-size           = 500M
 innodb-flush-log-at-trx-commit = 1
 innodb-file-per-table          = 1
 innodb-buffer-pool-size        = 1G
 character-set-server     = utf8mb4
 collation-server         = utf8mb4_general_ci
 skip-external-locking
 skip-host-cache
 skip-name-resolve
 log-queries-not-using-indexes  = 1
 slow-query-log                 = 1
 slow-query-log-file            = /data/mysql/mysql-slow.log
[jsadmin@ahq-vsvr10-0119 etc]$
```

so why does the mysqld can't start?

supplement:
memory info:

```
[jsadmin@ahq-vsvr10-0119 ~]$ cat /proc/meminfo
MemTotal:       32761648 kB
MemFree:        15545800 kB
MemAvailable:   29155252 kB
Buffers:            3144 kB
Cached:         14909264 kB
SwapCached:            0 kB
Active:         11288772 kB
Inactive:        4748276 kB
Active(anon):    2248488 kB
Inactive(anon):   510168 kB
Active(file):    9040284 kB
Inactive(file):  4238108 kB
Unevictable:         128 kB
Mlocked:             132 kB
SwapTotal:      16773116 kB
SwapFree:       16773116 kB
Dirty:                 0 kB
Writeback:             0 kB
AnonPages:       1124772 kB
Mapped:           114308 kB
Shmem:           1634012 kB
Slab:             843912 kB
SReclaimable:     733808 kB
SUnreclaim:       110104 kB
KernelStack:        7584 kB
PageTables:        11012 kB
NFS_Unstable:          0 kB
Bounce:                0 kB
WritebackTmp:          0 kB
CommitLimit:    33153940 kB
Committed_AS:    4910808 kB
VmallocTotal:   34359738367 kB
VmallocUsed:      236636 kB
VmallocChunk:   34359310332 kB
Percpu:            24064 kB
HardwareCorrupted:     0 kB
AnonHugePages:    507904 kB
CmaTotal:              0 kB
CmaFree:               0 kB
HugePages_Total:       0
HugePages_Free:        0
HugePages_Rsvd:        0
HugePages_Surp:        0
Hugepagesize:       2048 kB
DirectMap4k:      153408 kB
DirectMap2M:     9283584 kB
DirectMap1G:    26214400 kB
[jsadmin@ahq-vsvr10-0119 ~]$
```

cpu info:

```
[jsadmin@ahq-vsvr10-0119 ~]$ cat /proc/cpuinfo
processor       : 0
vendor_id       : GenuineIntel
cpu family      : 6
model           : 79
model name      : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2660 v4 @ 2.00GHz
stepping        : 1
microcode       : 0xb000036
cpu MHz         : 1997.686
cache size      : 35840 KB
physical id     : 0
siblings        : 4
core id         : 0
cpu cores       : 4
apicid          : 0
initial apicid  : 0
fpu             : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level     : 20
wp              : yes
flags           : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts nopl xtopology tsc_reliable nonstop_tsc aperfmperf eagerfpu pni pclmulqdq ssse3 fma cx16 pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand hypervisor lahf_lm abm 3dnowprefetch epb invpcid_single fsgsbase tsc_adjust bmi1 hle avx2 smep bmi2 invpcid rtm rdseed adx smap xsaveopt dtherm ida arat pln pts
bogomips        : 3995.37
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 42 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:

processor       : 1
vendor_id       : GenuineIntel
cpu family      : 6
model           : 79
model name      : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2660 v4 @ 2.00GHz
stepping        : 1
microcode       : 0xb000036
cpu MHz         : 1997.686
cache size      : 35840 KB
physical id     : 0
siblings        : 4
core id         : 1
cpu cores       : 4
apicid          : 1
initial apicid  : 1
fpu             : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level     : 20
wp              : yes
flags           : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts nopl xtopology tsc_reliable nonstop_tsc aperfmperf eagerfpu pni pclmulqdq ssse3 fma cx16 pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand hypervisor lahf_lm abm 3dnowprefetch epb invpcid_single fsgsbase tsc_adjust bmi1 hle avx2 smep bmi2 invpcid rtm rdseed adx smap xsaveopt dtherm ida arat pln pts
bogomips        : 3995.37
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 42 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:

processor       : 2
vendor_id       : GenuineIntel
cpu family      : 6
model           : 79
model name      : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2660 v4 @ 2.00GHz
stepping        : 1
microcode       : 0xb000036
cpu MHz         : 1997.686
cache size      : 35840 KB
physical id     : 0
siblings        : 4
core id         : 2
cpu cores       : 4
apicid          : 2
initial apicid  : 2
fpu             : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level     : 20
wp              : yes
flags           : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts nopl xtopology tsc_reliable nonstop_tsc aperfmperf eagerfpu pni pclmulqdq ssse3 fma cx16 pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand hypervisor lahf_lm abm 3dnowprefetch epb invpcid_single fsgsbase tsc_adjust bmi1 hle avx2 smep bmi2 invpcid rtm rdseed adx smap xsaveopt dtherm ida arat pln pts
bogomips        : 3995.37
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 42 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:

processor       : 3
vendor_id       : GenuineIntel
cpu family      : 6
model           : 79
model name      : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2660 v4 @ 2.00GHz
stepping        : 1
microcode       : 0xb000036
cpu MHz         : 1997.686
cache size      : 35840 KB
physical id     : 0
siblings        : 4
core id         : 3
cpu cores       : 4
apicid          : 3
initial apicid  : 3
fpu             : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level     : 20
wp              : yes
flags           : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts nopl xtopology tsc_reliable nonstop_tsc aperfmperf eagerfpu pni pclmulqdq ssse3 fma cx16 pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand hypervisor lahf_lm abm 3dnowprefetch epb invpcid_single fsgsbase tsc_adjust bmi1 hle avx2 smep bmi2 invpcid rtm rdseed adx smap xsaveopt dtherm ida arat pln pts
bogomips        : 3995.37
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 42 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:

processor       : 4
vendor_id       : GenuineIntel
cpu family      : 6
model           : 79
model name      : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2660 v4 @ 2.00GHz
stepping        : 1
microcode       : 0xb000036
cpu MHz         : 1997.686
cache size      : 35840 KB
physical id     : 1
siblings        : 4
core id         : 0
cpu cores       : 4
apicid          : 4
initial apicid  : 4
fpu             : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level     : 20
wp              : yes
flags           : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts nopl xtopology tsc_reliable nonstop_tsc aperfmperf eagerfpu pni pclmulqdq ssse3 fma cx16 pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand hypervisor lahf_lm abm 3dnowprefetch epb invpcid_single fsgsbase tsc_adjust bmi1 hle avx2 smep bmi2 invpcid rtm rdseed adx smap xsaveopt dtherm ida arat pln pts
bogomips        : 3995.37
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 42 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:

processor       : 5
vendor_id       : GenuineIntel
cpu family      : 6
model           : 79
model name      : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2660 v4 @ 2.00GHz
stepping        : 1
microcode       : 0xb000036
cpu MHz         : 1997.686
cache size      : 35840 KB
physical id     : 1
siblings        : 4
core id         : 1
cpu cores       : 4
apicid          : 5
initial apicid  : 5
fpu             : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level     : 20
wp              : yes
flags           : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts nopl xtopology tsc_reliable nonstop_tsc aperfmperf eagerfpu pni pclmulqdq ssse3 fma cx16 pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand hypervisor lahf_lm abm 3dnowprefetch epb invpcid_single fsgsbase tsc_adjust bmi1 hle avx2 smep bmi2 invpcid rtm rdseed adx smap xsaveopt dtherm ida arat pln pts
bogomips        : 3995.37
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 42 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:

processor       : 6
vendor_id       : GenuineIntel
cpu family      : 6
model           : 79
model name      : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2660 v4 @ 2.00GHz
stepping        : 1
microcode       : 0xb000036
cpu MHz         : 1997.686
cache size      : 35840 KB
physical id     : 1
siblings        : 4
core id         : 2
cpu cores       : 4
apicid          : 6
initial apicid  : 6
fpu             : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level     : 20
wp              : yes
flags           : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts nopl xtopology tsc_reliable nonstop_tsc aperfmperf eagerfpu pni pclmulqdq ssse3 fma cx16 pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand hypervisor lahf_lm abm 3dnowprefetch epb invpcid_single fsgsbase tsc_adjust bmi1 hle avx2 smep bmi2 invpcid rtm rdseed adx smap xsaveopt dtherm ida arat pln pts
bogomips        : 3995.37
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 42 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:

processor       : 7
vendor_id       : GenuineIntel
cpu family      : 6
model           : 79
model name      : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2660 v4 @ 2.00GHz
stepping        : 1
microcode       : 0xb000036
cpu MHz         : 1997.686
cache size      : 35840 KB
physical id     : 1
siblings        : 4
core id         : 3
cpu cores       : 4
apicid          : 7
initial apicid  : 7
fpu             : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level     : 20
wp              : yes
flags           : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts nopl xtopology tsc_reliable nonstop_tsc aperfmperf eagerfpu pni pclmulqdq ssse3 fma cx16 pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand hypervisor lahf_lm abm 3dnowprefetch epb invpcid_single fsgsbase tsc_adjust bmi1 hle avx2 smep bmi2 invpcid rtm rdseed adx smap xsaveopt dtherm ida arat pln pts
bogomips        : 3995.37
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 42 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:

[jsadmin@ahq-vsvr10-0119 ~]$
```

Comment: How much RAM is available to the server?  # cores?  Do you see that Process: 13625 failed?

Comment: I see Process: 13625, which one indicates that the ram is not enough? Do you mean "InnoDB: Setting file './ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ..."?

Comment: RAM size was just a question.  There is no warning about insufficient ram.  When setting tmp size ..... Please wait ......... is followed by  
 
Nov 16 22:34:00 ahq-vsvr10-0120 mysqld[13625]: 2022-11-16T14:34:00.091421Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: File './ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.  

Then you have a typical progression of startup with no problem through this request.

Comment: Observations about my.cnf content.  A) Most people do not have a space leading a configuration value on any line.  Yours are sometimes with leading space, sometimes without.  Consistency would be nice.  B) since SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES is consistent in using underscore as a separator in the display of global variable names, it is helpful to always use underscore rather than a hyphen to avoid confusion.  ( I realize this has been tolerated for years.)  C) is group_concat_max_len reasonable at 4G when max_allowed_packet has a 32M limit?

Comment: More observations, D) Limit hacker/cracker breakin attempts to 10 rather one million tolerated today with current max_connect_errors.  E) Do you have ANY MyISAM data tables?  If not you could remove skip_external_locking and no harm will be done. Please view profile for contact info.